# When a Rational function becomes a line?

Tags: rational-functions

Why is it that when $AD = BC$, this equation becomes a horizontal line?

$$y = \frac {Ax+B}{Cx+D} $$

For any other values where $AD$ isn't equal to $BC$ it is a rational function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}=\frac BD\frac{D(Ax+B)}{B(Cx+D)}=\frac BD\frac{ADx+BD}{\color{green}{BC}x+BD}=\frac BD\frac{ADx+BD}{\color{green}{AD}x+BD}=\frac BD.$$
Or
$$\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D}=\frac{Ax+B}{Cx+\dfrac{BC}A}=A\frac{Ax+B}{ACx+BC}=\frac AC\frac{Ax+B}{Ax+B}=\frac AC.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can show it like that :

$$ \frac{Ax+B}{Cx+D} = \frac{A}{C}\frac{Cx + B\frac{C}{A} }{Cx+D}$$
$$ = \frac{A}{C}\frac{Cx + D + (B\frac{C}{A}-D )}{Cx+D}$$
$$ = \frac{A}{C} + \frac{A}{C} \frac{ B\frac{C}{A}-D }{Cx+D}$$
$$ = \frac{A}{C} + \frac{1}{C} \frac{ BC-AD }{Cx+D}$$
$$ = \frac{A}{C} + 0$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $AD = BC$ and $C \ne 0$ or $D \ne 0$, otherwise the expression is not well defined.

Case $C \ne 0$, $D = 0$: This implies $BC = 0$, so we have $B = 0$ and
$$
y = \frac{Ax}{C x} = \frac{A}{C} 
$$
which is a constant function.

Case $C=0$, $D \ne 0$: This implies $AD = 0$, so we have $A=0$ and
$$
y = \frac{B}{D}
$$
which is a constant function as well.

Case $C \ne 0$, $D \ne 0$: So we have $A = (BC)/D$ and
$$
y = \frac{Ax + B}{C x + D}
= \frac{((BC)/D) x + B}{Cx + D}
= \frac{BC x + BD}{D(Cx + D)}
= \frac{B(C x + D)}{D(Cx + D)} = \frac{B}{D}
$$
So we always get some constant function.